# Network Mapped Drives sensitive information leakage when changing LAN networks on Windows

Tags: windows, security, network-share, local-area-network, network-security

Assuming the following or similar setup of network drives/locations on a Windows 7+ system originally connected to a TrustedLAN:

- TrustedLAN Gateway: 192.168.1.1 /24
- TrustedLAN Windows System IP: 192.168.1.10
- NAS's IP on TrustedLAN: 192.168.1.20 (this is where actual folders that are shared with Windows system are located)
- Network-Mapped Drive Z: \\192.168.1.20\SharedFolder1 (username, password required)
- Network Location: \\192.168.1.20\SharedFolder2 (username, password required)

Which of the following can / will be "leaked" to a *new UntrustedLAN* when the Windows computer (where network locations are originally mapped) is connected to *it* (if and when it tries to reconnect these network locations (which would not be present on the *new UntrustedLAN*))? :

- Network drive/location IP address
- Network shared folder name (path) / share name
- Credentials (username and/or password)

By "leak" I mean information (packets) sent via Ethernet cable that connects Windows system with the new UntrustedLAN (or equivalently a different WiFi network if wireless connection is used).

Is there any difference if the new UntrustedLAN has the same Gateway IP address (but obviously different MAC address) - e.g. 192.168.1.1, or a different IP address like 172.16.0.1?

Is there any difference if the new UntrustedLAN is marked as Public vs Private in Windows UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing of that will be "leaked".

The computer will try to connect to a server which is not there. A network sniffer will only see a TCP connection attempt; but since the connection never will get established, application-specific details such as requests for a specific SMB share or logon information will not be exchanged at all.

Comment: Thank you for an unambiguous answer. But wouldn't that first TCP packet also contain the application protocol's (SMB's)-specific payload as well?

Comment: No. The TCP handshake (SYN - SYN ACK - ACK) doens't contain any payload, actual data transmission only begins *after* a successful connection has been established.